# Is it possible to access a Telnet server via SRV-Record?

Tags: telnet, srv-record

I wanted to make a little telnet server using PHP as an addition to my website, which already looks like a terminal.

I could create the `telnet.example.com`-subdomain, but that will take away the effect of the website beeing an actual terminal.

The transfer can be telnet, because there is no sensitive data sent between user and server.

I'm using Cloudflare, so I can't just connect to the server, it needs to be SRV.

Is there a standard for SRV-records, that all Telnet-Clients support?

And if yes: What is the correct name for the "Service"?

Comment: a) Why telnet? b) What's wrong with just connecting to port 21 on your server? c) Why telnet? d) And no telnet client will query SRV records to my knowledge.

Comment: a) It doesn't need to be encrypted and should only be a little addon to my website, which looks like a terminal b) Cloudflare c) See a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SRV` record is just a DNS resource record which provides a layer of indirection between a resource (in this case, a telnet server) and the name used to access that resource. There's nothing *stopping* you putting a service record up under the name `_telnet._tcp.<yourdomain>` to publish your `telnet` daemon to the world.

Don't expect many clients to connect to your published resource, though. There is [limited support](http://dns.vanrein.org/srv/tools/)<sup>1</sup> for this method. You'll need to re-think your approach.

> I could create the `telnet.example.com`-subdomain, but that will take away the effect of the website beeing an actual terminal.

A web page can incorporate resources from numerous locations, and can connect to other locations to exchange data. Why not embed [one](https://github.com/mkozjak/node-telnet-client) of [several](https://www.npmjs.com/package/another-telnet-client) JavaScript-based `telnet` clients in the webpage itself, which you can custom configure to connect to a `telnet` server hosted on another FQDN of your choice. You could even add support to the code to check a `SRV` record and use that approach to initiate the connection.

If you maintain you have a genuine need (or interest) to provide a `telnet` service for visitors to your website, I recommend you adopt a suitable naming convention which does the work of getting users to your publicly-available `telnet` service for you:

- `www.<yourdomain>` is for your web server, hosted via CloudFlare in this instance. `www` stands for **W**orld **W**ide **W**eb. Most users wouldn't associate such an FQDN with also providing a `telnet` service, much less treat its existence as a call-to-action to open their terminal and connect in this fashion.
- `telnet.<yourdomain>` is for your `telnet` daemon, wherever this is hosted. The name automatically implies a `telnet` service runs at this address, and will prompt true geeks to endeavour to connect via a suitable telnet client.

You can publish the latter on the website hosted at the former. If you use the `telnet://` scheme in the URI, some browsers might understand what to do with this. I hope you've got a plurality of technically-proficient visitors though!

---

There's a good example of shelling out to a `telnet` client to do something interesting (although not necessarily practically useful) on the website of [this well-known set of `telnet` services](http://www.blinkenlights.nl/services.html).

---

<sup>1</sup>: I've included this link as a third-party reference to clarify the *limited support* claim. Only one `telnet` client which supposedly has `SRV` record support is linked, and the link is sadly dead! The implication is that this is not a suitable approach to achieve your desired objective.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer, but `_telnet` didn't work as a service :/